# Hidden async function

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await

I am trying to create a library, which only has one public function, which returns an enum.  The private function, that powers this based on my requirements, has to be async due to android platform.  What I want to do, is make the only public function be consumed as a non-async function.  I know this may see counter-intuitive, but I have my reasons.  As far as the consumer of the function is concerned, they have always had to run the code as synchronous before, and this requirement does not change now that it is wrapped in a more efficient library.  I don't want to make them do await method.  They don't have to know, that is what is going on behind the scenes.

Here is what I have so far, but I am struggling with the public method:

```
public enum DialogResult
{
    Button1 = 1,
    Button2 = 2,
    Button3 = 3,
}

class MsgBox
{
    public  DialogResult Show(String Title, String Caption, Context context)
    {


    }

    private async Task<DialogResult> ShowAsync(String Title, String Caption, Context context)
    {
        return await BuildAsync(Title, Caption, context);
    }

    private Task<DialogResult> BuildAsync(String Title, String Caption,Context context)
    {
        var r = new TaskCompletionSource<DialogResult>();

        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .SetPositiveButton("Yes", (sender, args) =>
        {
            // User pressed yes
            r.SetResult(DialogResult.Button1);
        })
        .SetNegativeButton("No", (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Do nothing
            r.SetResult(DialogResult.Button2);
        })

        .SetMessage(Caption)
        .SetTitle(Title)
        .Show();

        return r.Task;

    }

}
```

In summary; I need this public function to just return my plain DialogResult once it has returned from ShowAsync, and not require itself to be called with await.

Comment: Like `ShowAsync(...).Result`?

Comment: Thanks DavidG, but I tried this, and it deadlocks the UI.

Comment: How about with `ConfigureAwait`?

Comment: Again, I tried ConfigureAwait(false) and it still appears to run on the main threadpool.  Thank you for your help, though.

Comment: It's going to need to be asynchronous.  That's just inherent to the nature of working with a UI like this.  You aren't going to be able to make the method synchronous; any attempt to do so would just block the UI thread.

Comment: Don't do "sync over async". Choose, either async all the way, or sync all the way. If your consumer must be synchronous don't use async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest and best answer is "you can't". Think about what you're trying to do: your code needs to use an API that needs to *return execution to the message loop* on the UI thread before it completes, but the code calling your code needs to *block the UI thread* until your code completes. It's a logically impossible design.

However, there are [a couple hacks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) you can use to try to force it to work. One option is to offload the work to another thread; however, that won't work in your case because the API you're using needs to run on the UI thread. The remaining hack is to run a nested message loop.

There is one very serious problem with running a nested message loop: reentrancy. Essentially, once you have a nested message loop, your customers' entire application needs to handle reentrancy. This is the reason why "`DoEvents` is evil". This is a huge requirement to push on your customers, far more complex to explain and support than just making the method `async`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, and attempt to hack a solution.  Agreed, the hack is best avoided.  I guess I will have to accept defeat, like the many before me.